# validates :presence vs validates_presence_of using rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a couple of simple models that are associated like so:

MODELS

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :name, :presence => true, :message => 'Name cannot be blank, Task not saved'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end
```

VIEW has a call in it like so:
`user.tasks` <-- then I loop through the tasks

The Issue:

In the task model --

when I use:

```
validates :name, :presence => true ,  :message => 'Name cannot be blank, Task not saved'
```

I get a 500 error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant User::Task):
NameError in View file
```

when I use:

```
validates_presence_of :name
```

Everything works.

I thought the both validates methods above where the same...is the issue have to do with associations and how validation tie into associated models.  I have a hunch that something is going on with the way things are associated, but it is just a hunch.

Any help will be appreciated.  Thank very much.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

When you use the newer `validates :name` format, you can put multiple validations in one line rather than having to have multiple lines for each type of validation. Because of this, when Rails hits your `:message` parameter, it thinks it's a validation method rather than a message associated with `:presence`. Try this instead:

```
validates :name, :presence => {:message => 'Name cannot be blank, Task not saved'}
```

Also, depending on how you display your errors, this error may actually show up as 'Name Name cannot be....'; if so, you'll want to set the message to just 'cannot be blank, Task not saved'.

Comment: I have a question about internationalization with regard to this. If Rails provides the field name, how can this error message be completely localized? For instance, in spanish, 'name' should be 'nombre'. Is there any way to suppress the default message completely?

Comment: I know this is an old post but where should this error message be displayed, and does it show after submitting the form for example? thank you