# Rails 3 validations are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have migrated my application from Rails 2.3.5 to Rails 3.

I have validations present in the model like

```
validates :name, :presence => {:message => "Please enter the name"}
```

I am getting error. The error is pointing to the line where I added the validations. The error log is as follows

```
activemodel (3.2.2) lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:85:in `block in validates_with'
activemodel (3.2.2) lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:83:in `each'
activemodel (3.2.2) lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:83:in `validates_with'
activemodel (3.2.2) lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:99:in `block in validates'
activemodel (3.2.2) lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:90:in `each'
activemodel (3.2.2) lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:90:in `validates'
app/models/business.rb:19:in `<class:Business>'
app/models/business.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Maybe this link helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078990/validates-presence-vs-validates-presence-of-using-rails-3

Comment: I tried it.But its not working.

Comment: Solved this problem. I defined method setup in the lib module which is actually present in the validations module

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
validates :name, :presence => true, :message => "Please enter the name"
```

Comment: Yes, I tried with
    validates  :name,:presence => {:message => "select atleast one option" }

But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
validates_presence_of :name, :message => "Please enter the name"
```