# Validating the phone number with a regex ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to validate if the phone number is a digit or not :-

This is my user.rg

```
 number_regex = /\d[0-9]\)*\z/


 validates_format_of :phone, :with =>  number_regex, :message => "Only positive number without spaces are allowed"
```

This is my view.html.haml

```
%li
   %strong=f.label :phone, "Phone Number"
   =f.text_field :phone, :placeholder => "Your phone number"
```

This is controller

```
def edit_profile
        @user = current_user
        request.method.inspect
        if request.method == "POST"
            if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
                sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
                flash[:success] = "You have updated your profile successfully"
                redirect_to dashboard_index_path
            else
                flash[:error] = "Profile could not be updated"
                render :action => "edit_profile"
            end
        end  
    end
```

When I enter the number in the text field for the first time it validates prperly, but if I enter the correct format and then try to enter the wrong format it skips validations and I get a flash message that profile has been successfully updated, however the wrong value (with letters) is not saved.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: At least sanitize the field a bit. When I get messages like 'no whitespace allowed' I'm like "noobs again".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I use this, :with => "no problem".

```
validates :phone,:presence => true,
                 :numericality => true,
                 :length => { :minimum => 10, :maximum => 15 }
```

If you want a message,**(not a MASSAGE)**, try this,

```
 validates :phone,   :presence => {:message => 'hello world, bad operation!'},
                     :numericality => true,
                     :length => { :minimum => 10, :maximum => 15 }
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078990/validates-presence-vs-validates-presence-of-using-rails-3) question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    validates_format_of :phone, :with =>  /\d[0-9]\)*\z/ , :message => "Only positive number without spaces are allowed"
```

Comment: This works if I try to enter alphabets for the first time. But if I enter say "1234lkgfdgdkj" after 1234 was saved it shows that the profile was updated successfully. If you check the phone number from console the value is still 1234 but I do not get flash[:error]